# Storing the Content of MediaPlayer (QML/Qt)

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

I'm developing a phone application using `Qt`. I have used `Qt C++ classes` for my whole app but at some point I had to use `Qt QML Types` for phone **camera function** in my application and now I am able to display camera's content on a `MediaPlayer`. I was wondering if it is possible to aslo save this content on phone storage as a `.mp4` file or any other formats?

Here is a piece of the code where I display this content on `MediaPlayer`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Item {
    id: videoPreview
    property alias source : player.source
    signal closed

    MediaPlayer {

        id: player
        autoPlay: true

        onStatusChanged: {
            if (status == MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia)
                videoPreview.closed();
        }
    }

    VideoOutput {
        source: player
        anchors.fill : parent
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            videoPreview.closed();
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any kind of hints or helps since I'm a beginner in `QML Types` :).

And hereby is my main QML file.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.4

Rectangle {
    id : cameraUI

    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "black"
    state: "VideoCapture"

    states: [

        State {
            name: "VideoCapture"
            StateChangeScript {

                script: {
                    camera.position = Camera.FrontFace
                    camera.captureMode = Camera.CaptureVideo
                    camera.start()
                }
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "VideoPreview"
            StateChangeScript {
                script: {
                    camera.stop()
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    Camera {
        id: camera
        captureMode: Camera.CaptureVideo

        videoRecorder {

             resolution: "640x480"
             frameRate: 30
        }
    }

    VideoPreview {
        id : videoPreview
        anchors.fill : parent
        onClosed: cameraUI.state = "VideoCapture"
        visible: cameraUI.state == "VideoPreview"
        focus: visible

        //don't load recorded video if preview is invisible
        source: visible ? camera.videoRecorder.actualLocation : ""
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: viewfinder
        visible: cameraUI.state == "VideoCapture"

        x: 0
        y: 0
       // width: parent.width
        width: parent.width - stillControls.buttonsPanelWidth
        height: parent.height

        source: camera
        autoOrientation: true
    }

    VideoCaptureControls {
        id: videoControls
        anchors.fill: parent
        camera: camera
        visible: cameraUI.state == "VideoCapture"
        onPreviewSelected: cameraUI.state = "VideoPreview"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. For more properties check [CameraRecorder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camerarecorder.html) documentation.

```
  Camera
        {
            id: camera
            captureMode: Camera.CaptureVideo
            videoRecorder.muted: true // set any property of recording.
        }

        VideoOutput 
        {
            source: camera
            width: parent.width*0.8
            height: parent.height*0.8
            autoOrientation: true
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            MouseArea
            {
                property var myInt:0
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked:
                {
                    camera.searchAndLock()
                    camera.videoRecorder.record()
                    if( myInt > 1 )
                    {
                        camera.videoRecorder.stop()
                        console.log(camera.videoRecorder.outputLocation)
                    }
                    myInt=myInt+1
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do I need to create another QML file for this?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to do. Copying the code above anywhere should work. If it fixes your problem can you mark answer as accepted ?

Comment: I have added it on my main QML file which I have defined Camera and Videooutput there but it doesn't seem to store the video. What it does that by the first time of tapping on the screen it starts recording. Would you kindly explain more about this so I can modify the code correctly? @Muhammet Ali Asan

Comment: I will provide you my main QML file on my question section since it is too long to be posted as a comment. please refer to the above code.

Comment: from console i retrieved this **libFastPong.so: qml: file:///data/user/0/org.qtproject.example.FastPong/files/VID_00000048.mp4** but I can not find such a file. Do you what the probelm can be?

Comment: I am not very good at Android but as far as I know, that location is only accessed by your application. If you want to export the video you should programmatically copy that file from there to a location which can be accessed.